# how to query the chain index tx endpoint?

Tags: plutus-pab, pab

The following curl is constructed via swagger that says it just needs the string, but this fails.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$curl -X 'POST' \
>   'http://localhost:9083/tx' \
>   -H 'accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
>   -d '"c42669c4818e04d732e77b9ed3efb22697ba4b1cd7540d2bab8c44f9a5e4fbb6"'
Error in $: parsing Plutus.V1.Ledger.TxId.TxId(TxId) failed, expected Object, but encountered String
```

I can pull out the tx data in sqlite3 so I think I've ruled out it being a bad id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following substitution works

```
...
-d '{"getTxId" : "c42669c4818e04d732e77b9ed3efb22697ba4b1cd7540d2bab8c44f9a5e4fbb6"}'
...
```