# Using chain-index endpoints

Tags: chain-index

Hitting the chain index endpoint to query utxo just gives `Bad Request` as response.
Tried this on testnet where `txOutRefId` is the `tx hash` of a testnet transaction. Screenshot is attached.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:9083/unspent-tx-out' \
  -H 'accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
  -d '{
  "txOutRefId": "32178b5f5af6c2ac963adef07284f35cb7a86ff1cdd18e119007631607a28b84",
  "txOutRefIdx": 0
}'
```

[image]

Unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Has anyone been able to use this endpoint?

Note: Chain index is synced and `/tip` endpoint works.

***Update:***
This seems to be required format for the endpoint

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:9083/unspent-tx-out' \
  -H 'accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
  -d '{
  "txOutRefId": {"getTxId":"3961a841f5af32d3878cd816a23c9da7b3c3bb586e3b3db5fba1579bd1408a20"},
  "txOutRefIdx": 0
}'
```

Howeve my chain-index responded with this

```
Delete your chain index database and resync.
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Plutus/ChainIndex/DbSchema.hs:232:22 in plutus-chain-index-core-0.1.0.0-inplace:Plutus.ChainIndex.DbSchema
```

Beats me why it asks for a resync. Resyncing chain index will take days, so I have not gone ahead to try that :)

Comment: What error does curl return when run in the terminal?

Comment: @waalge: Thanks for that comment. Terminal gives. 
Error in $.txOutRefId: parsing Plutus.V1.Ledger.TxId.TxId(TxId) failed, expected Object, but encountered String

Seems it expects the TxId object defined in Plutus as TxId { getTxId :: PlutusTx.BuiltinByteString }. 
Will try it out

Answer (score 0):

[how to query the chain index tx endpoint?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/how-to-query-the-chain-index-tx-endpoint/7734#7734)

I think you are probably still seeing this.
This happens on a number of the apis.
Shame swagger doesn't return the actual error. It would save some time.

Comment: I changed the object in the payload and got a response, not the one I expected though. I have added the info as updates to the question.

Comment: the chain-index is such a headache that I gave up. Bon courage.